# Is there a known shorter axiomatization of NF than this?

Tags: reference-request, set-theory, lo.logic, axioms, new-foundations

Is there an already known axiomtization of $NF$ that is **shorter** than the following axiomatic system in first order logic with equality $``="$ and membership $``\in"$? And what is exactly meant by *shorter* is having less total number of symbols in all of its axioms than the total number of symbols in all axioms of this system.

1. **Extensionality:** as in $NF$
2. **Complements:** $\forall A \exists x \forall y(y \in x \leftrightarrow y \not \in A)$
3. **Pairing:** $ \forall a,b \exists x \forall y(y \in x \leftrightarrow y=a \lor y=b) $
4. **Set union:** $ \forall A \exists x \forall y(y \in x \leftrightarrow \exists m \in A (y \in m)) $
5. **Frege $ 1^*$:** $\exists x \forall y(y \in x \leftrightarrow\exists z \forall m \in y \ (z=m))$
6. **Product:**
   $\forall R,S \exists x \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow \exists r \in R \ \exists s \in S \\ \forall  z \in y \ ( z \in s \lor z \in r))$
7. **Unordered intersection relation set:**
   $\exists x \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow \exists z \forall m \in y (z \in m))$

The already known finite axiomatizations of $NF$ present in literature that I know of are those of Hailperin and Randall Holmes (see [here](http://zaljohar.tripod.com/acyclic_abstract_final.pdf) Pages: 7,15), and those are very long compared to the above mentioned one.

Comment: "shorter" in what way? Clearly you can take conjunction of all the axioms to get a one-axiom aximatization.

Comment: shorter means the total number of symbols in the open expansion of all of the axioms.

Comment: Surely you can cramp them more compactly into one axiom. Two universal axioms $\forall x:\phi(x)$ and $\forall y:\psi(y)$ can be replaced by $\forall x:\phi(x)\wedge\psi(y)$.

Comment: you mean $\forall x : \phi(x) \wedge \psi(x) $, notice that you are adding the $\wedge$s, but anyhow I'm asking about a really different system from that, and not just a trivial shortening of this system itself

Comment: For this question to make sense you should explain very precisely what language you are using. For instance, I see $\{y \mid \phi(y)\}$, which normally is not part of first-order logic languages. Are you using a first-order language? What is the signature?

Comment: short axiomatization of $NF$ means in the same language of $NF$ which is first order logic with equality and membership, and the abstraction $\{ | \} $$ is a definable symbol,  Anyhow I'll re-write it without it

Comment: @Wojowu I'm asking about "Known" short axiomatizations of $NF$, this means something that had already been there "before" I've presented the above axiomatization, not something that would come after.

Comment: So if anyone thinks of ways of shortening your axioms, they should travel to the past and present them from there? :-)

Comment: I'm asking people who know of short axiomatizations of $NF$ that is ALREADY present in the literature, if there is a known one that is shorter than the one presented here, I personally only know the two that I've referenced above. Thinking of ways of shortening THIS system is totally irrelevant to the question, since it won't be something that is already present in the literature.If anyone thinks of ways of shortening this system of axioms, he need not present it as an answer to this question, because it is not what that question is asking?

Comment: How many symbols are there in $y \notin A$ or $\forall m \in y$? The standard answers are 6 (from $\neg(y\in A)$) and 8 (from $\forall m(m\in y\implies\ )$), so it'd be clearer to display the axioms in the question without abbreviations.

Comment: About axiom 2: shouldn't it be $\ \rightarrow\ $ rather than $\ \leftrightarrow\ $ ?

Comment: @WlodAA No, axiom 2 is about existence of absolute complements and so we must use the bi-conditional.

Comment: @ZuhairAl-Johar, right, thank you. I had an illusion of seeing $\ \exists_{x\in A}.\ $

Comment: As a personal opinion:Finding an axiom system (more generally: a description) of a class  $K$ of objects which is (at least apparently) essentially _different_  from known axioms/descriptions can express a deep truth about $K$, and can help understand $K$ better. Finding one that is merely _shorter_ seems less helpful/interesting to me. When comparing two axiom systems of humanly readable length for $K$, the shorter one will often be more difficult to understand. (Not always, though; the axiom system {"false"} is very easily understood, but I will not  claim that it is equivalent to NF.)

Comment: @Goldstern, short axiomatization can be technically useful, for example in proving consistency of a system. For example here one can easily prove Con(NFU) given the existence of an external automorphism on a model of Zermelo that inwardly move ranks. One can easily interpret the above seven axioms. So it is not out of merits. Not only that, seeing the above axioms one can figure out that the need for automorphism in Boffa models in not necessary, you only need an rank shifting embedding that preserves a handful amount of sentences. If you make that a bijection then you get Con(NF).