# Is this fragment of NF known to be consistent?

Tags: lo.logic, new-foundations

The following theory is a [fragment of $\small \sf NF$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Foundations#Axioms_and_stratification). My question is about if it is known to be consistent ***without*** assuming the consistency of $\small\sf NF$.

The language is of first order logic with equality and membership.

**Axioms:**

**1. Extnesionality:** $\forall x \forall y (\forall z ( z \in x \leftrightarrow z \in y ) \to x=y)$

**2. Comprehension:** if $\phi(y)$ is a formula in which $y$ only occurs free, and $x$ not occurring free, having no more than one occurrence of an atomic sub-formula that contains a bound variable in $\phi(y)$ and $y$, and having no more than one occurrence of an atomic sub-formula containing two bound variables in $\phi(y)$, otherwise all atomic sub-formulas must contain a parameter; then all closures of: $$\exists x \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow \phi(y))$$; are axioms.

Terminology: by atomic formula here it is meant a formula having exactly two occurrences of variable symbols and one primitive predicate symbol, i.e. either $\in$ or $=$, in between. By *parameters* of a formula $\phi(y)$ its meant any free variable symbol in $\phi(y)$ other than the symbol $``y"$. The primitive logical connectives are the customary four ones and the bi-conditional.

/Theory definition finished.

Now this theory is a fragment of $\small \sf NF$, since all so qualified formulas in comprehension are [weakly stratified](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stratification_(mathematics)#In_set_theory)! IF we in addition allow for the formula to have two atomic sub-formulas with bound variables (instead of one) provided that the total number of variables in those two atomic sub-formulas must be more than two, then we get [full $\small \sf NF$](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/313418/is-there-a-known-shorter-axiomatization-of-nf-than-this).

This theory is not a part of a [known fragment of NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_Foundations#The_consistency_problem_and_related_partial_results) like [Predicative $\small \sf NF$](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/quine-nf/), nor of [Impredicative $\small \sf NF$](https://dial.uclouvain.be/pr/boreal/object/boreal:57616/datastream/PDF_01/view), nor of $\small \sf NF_3$, nor is of [Tupailo's NFSI](http://logoi.be/crabbe/textes/NFSIdraft.pdf)

My guess is that its very weak and thus consistent.

Comment: If you believe Randall's proof, then all the fragments of NF are consistent...

Comment: @AsafKaragila, that's why I asked for a proof that is independent of consistency of NF, if this fragment is strictly weaker than NF, then it must be the case that it can be proved consistent without the need for consistency of NF. Holmes's proof of NF is monstrously complex, so I've asked here for a proof that doesn't depend on that.

Comment: I'm having difficulty parsing your restriction on comprehension. Could you give some examples of formulas that are and are not allowed?

Comment: @JamesHanson, Nice, please look at the link to full NF that I've wrote (end of fourth line from below), there all the defining formulas are examples of that comprehension EXCEPT the formula of the axiom of "Product" because it contains two occurrences of atomic subformulas with solely bound variables that are $z, r, s$,

Comment: In nutshell in order to know which formula is allowed you just examine its atomic subformulas, those should contain a parameter, if not and it contains the symbol $y$, so the other symbol is a bound variable, then only one such  atomic subformula is allowed, if both variable symbols in an atomic subformula are bound then no more than one such atomic subformula is allowed and it must contain TWO distinct variables.

Comment: other examples of not allowed formulas are those having an atomic subformula with two occurrences of the symbol y like $y \in y$ or $y=y$, also having more than one atomic subformula with occurrences of $y$ and a bound variable, or having an atomic subformula containing ONE bound variable like $\exists x (x \in x \land..)$, etc.